# How to specify the second table in an html file for C#

Tags: c#, linq, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I need to get the sum of the 4th row of the second table. 
I want to sum beginning with the second column. 
How do I do this?

```
    static void Main()
    {
        String htmlFile = "C:/Temp/Test_11.html";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(htmlFile);

        //var sum = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")  // <<<< No error when I access the first table 
        var sum = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]")  // <<<< Error when I try to access the 2nd table
            .Elements("tr")
            // Skip this many rows from the top
            .Skip(1)
            // .ElementAt(2) = third column
            .Sum(tr => int.Parse(tr.Elements("td").ElementAt(2).InnerText));
        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Below is the html file consisting of two tables. 
The result of the sum should be 26.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Environment1</th>
    <th>Databases</th>
    <th>Sites</th>
    <th>Site Collection Storage Used (GB)</th>
    <th>Ref</th>
</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Public1</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>32.6602</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Local1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>21.0506</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shared1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>17.092</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Environment2</th>
    <th>Databases</th>
    <th>Sites</th>
    <th>Site Collection Storage Used (GB)</th>
    <th>Ref</th>
 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Public2</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>31.5602</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Local2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>7.0302</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shared2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>13.109</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this

Comment: First try to select only the "tr" elements and then ensure that all the cells in the table which you parse using int is having value. Also it is always a good practice to check if there is any value and then to go for a int.parse. Also try to use int.tryparse instead. It is more safer.

Comment: Hi Saravanan, I believe I didn't make my issue clear enough. Please see my newly edited code above. Note that when I use the statement  `"//table"` I can successfully access the first table in the html file. (I have also edited my original post to include the html file.) The sum I get is correctly 46. However what I want to be able to do is access the second table. I tried doing this with `"//table[2]"` however that is not correct because I receive the error shown. What is the correct syntax in this context to access the second table. (I would revalue the value 26 returned.) Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sample does the same, the only concern is that I have hardcoded the positions and the elements in the xPath, which you can freely change to accommodate you requirement.

```
var tbl = xdoc.SelectNodes("//table[2]//tr[4]//td[position()>1]");

// In order to select the 1st table, the following statement can be used.
//var tbl = xdoc.SelectNodes("//table[2]//tr[4]//td[position()>1]");

int sum = 0;

foreach (XmlNode item in tbl) 
{
     decimal value = 0;
     if (decimal.TryParse(item.InnerText, out value))
     {
         sum += (int)value;
     }
 }

 Console.WriteLine("Number of (Web Application) sites: " + sum);
```

There are couple of points to note. You have values in decimal and have treated them like an integer. Hence I have used the decimal temporary variable to get all values and then done integer casting. This is however not the best practice. You have to look into that based on your exact requirement.

Additionally, i have used the `TryParse` so that only the items that can be parsed can be used for the calculation.

Please share your understanding here.

Comment: First, I need some help with how to use xPath in C#. What do I use in the "using" area at the top of my code? `.SelectNodes` is not recognized.

Comment: Please use this `using System.Xml;`

Comment: I have it working! Thank you! I will mark it answered shortly. ~ You have answered my question using System.xml. Others have answered other questions I have had using System.Linq or System.HtmlAgilityPack or something else. Are there resources you can suggest that discuss the various approaches?

Comment: Would you explain `//tr[4]` and `//td[position()` of the syntax of `("//table[2]//tr[4]//td[position()>1]")` I am a bit mystified because it is the third column we are looking at.

Comment: Please note that this approach that i have suggested is using xPath Queries. This is not only specific to .Net, you can use it any language that provides support for xPath. Please learn more from : http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/ and http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I can't get this to repeat. If I change the `//table[2]` in `"//table[2]//tr[4]//td[position()>1]"` to `//table[1]` I do not get the total of the corresponding column in the first table. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am able to get the total to be `41` for table[1]. I use the following code `xdoc.SelectNodes("//table[2]//tr[4]//td[position()>1]");`.
Please beware of any spaces in the xPath query that you form

Comment: Okay, I understand your expression now. This will help me. Thanks! (I was looking for something a little different, but I see that my question was unclear. I will edit my question consistent with your great reply so that it will be useful to others.)

Comment: @user1944272: Thanks for clarifying the details in the the post. Please update it and meanwhile i will also provide a comment on this post for the above expression. so this answer can be re-used.

Comment: @user1944272: I have updated the post so that you can mark it as an answer.